# Searching page content with a partial string from a HTML input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexof

So I'm trying to implement a basic search functionality on a page. I have a page structured from multiple `<div>` and a search bar `<input>` like so:

```
<input id="search" type="text">

<div class="panel-flex">
    <h4>Title One</h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-flex">
    <h4>Title Two</h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-flex">
    <h4>Title Three</h4>
</div>
```

As you type in to the search bar, any `<h4>` that does not contain the current value will be removed from the page. This is my code so far, but I can't find a way of getting a partial search match to happen, only an exact match.

For instance, if you searched `t` then everything would show, but if you searched `th` then only `Title Three` would show.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
        var searchTerm = $(this).val();
        $(".panel-flex").each(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            if ($(this).find("h4").text() == searchTerm) {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I want something that works like PHP's `strpos()` function, and all investigation led me to the JavaScript function `indexOf()`, but attempting to implement that in my code breaks it even more.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
        var searchTerm = $(this).val();
        $(".panel-flex").each(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            if ($(this).find("h4").indexOf(searchTerm) != -1) {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: indexof is the right tool but the immediate problem is you're calling it on the element and not the text of the element, it works on a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using  `.filter();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
        $('.panel-flex').hide();
        var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
         $('.panel-flex').filter(function(){
              return  $(this).find("h4").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
        }).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" type="text">

<div class="panel-flex">
    <h4>Title One</h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-flex">
    <h4>Title Two</h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-flex">
    <h4>Title Three</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider case sensitivity:

```
searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
$(".panel-flex").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("h4").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) == -1) {
        $(this).hide();
    } else {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```